# php cli mssql_connect - Unable to connect: SQL server is unavailable

Tags: php, cakephp, command-line-interface

Im trying to run a shell with cakephp but I'm not able to do it due to a SQL connection error, I'm always getting this

Warning:mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: XXXXX I'm sure the config for the data source is correct as I'm able to connect using the website side of the app.

Have anyone stumble with something like this?

BTW the webserver and the mssql server are not the same, they are on different hosts.

Environment Info ( I agree is a mess... ):

- Web server

  - Windows server 2003 R2
  - PHP-5.2.4
  - IBM http server 6.1
  - Cakephp 1.2
- DB Server

  - Windows server 2003 R2
  - Microsoft SQL server 2005

I have isolated the problem and found is not cakephp related, I created a script with just this line of code

```
mssql_connect('XXXX', 'YYYY', 'ZZZZ', true);
```

Giving me the same error. This should be something different between CLI and how php is run from the HTTP server.

Thank you!

Comment: Does your CLI php.ini have the mssql extensions enabled?

Comment: I'm on a window server, I executed "php -i" to get the php.ini being used and from that file I can confirm mssql is enabled for the CLI mssql

MSSQL Support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Library version => 7.0
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mssql.allow_persistent => On => On
mssql.batchsize => 0 => 0
mssql.compatability_mode => Off => Off
mssql.connect_timeout => 5 => 5
mssql.datetimeconvert => On => On
mssql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mssql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mssql.max_procs => Unlimited => Unlimited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I followed to narrow and then fix the problem:

- Check which php.ini is your cli using by running the next command: `php -i`
- Isolate the problem, I was thinking it was something with cakephp, but at the end every problem is related to a single line in php, my problem was around this line of code `mssql_connect('XXXX', 'YYYY', 'ZZZZ', true);`
- Based on the info provided [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40034) I found out that the next dll was outdated or not compatible with Windows Server 2003, just get ntwdblib.dll ver. 2000.80.2039.0, use this exact version as others like ver.2000.80.194.0 didn't worked for me.

As @charles mentioned if you are not working already in a project already deployed use sqlsrv drivers as those are maintained currently and the mssql are basically getting deprecated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify the port to connect to (usually 1433). If that still doesn't work its possible you need to play with named pipes settings. More information can be found in the comments on the PHP site: https://www.php.net/function.mssql-connect

I would also suggest you look into using the Microsoft SQL Serv drivers for PHP, they are much better maintained than the mssql ones. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20098 Here is an article explaining the differences: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/08/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-what-s-the-difference-part-1.aspx If you do go the sqlsrv route (and I really suggest you do) here are the connection parameters: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php Use example 3.

Comment: Thanks @Charles , I'll check that, I also found that when I restart the web server, php is having troubles to initialize curl, do you think that is related to cli not being able to connect to the db server?

Comment: No, Curl is seperate from the DB. Sounds like curl extension isnt loaded? Can you paste some lines from the error log?

Comment: Here is what the event viewer is logging: `The following information is part of the event: php[1072], PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_curl.dll' - The operating system cannot run php[1072]. in Unknown on line 0.`

Comment: In php.ini is the extension dir E:\Program Files\PHP\ext\ and is the curl dll there? If you dont need curl try disabling it and restarting the web server.

Comment: ok, that removed the errors from the php logs about curl, I also isolate the problem into a single php script that only has this line:  `mssql_connect('XXXX', 'YYYY', 'ZZZZ', true);` and the error still happens so it's not cake related... about moving to sql server drivers, I need to search if cakephp 1.2 is really compatible with that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I found the real issue based on this [link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40034), do you know if I should mark your answer as the one or write what I did based on this link, Thank you very much for your time @charles you really helped me :)

Comment: Glad you were able to fix your issue. Be careful when using the mssql driver that you dont truncate any varchar/nvarchar fields that have lengths > 255. We ran into this problem a few years back when doing a migration to mysql.